# How to create a widget with lot of buttons?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

This is probably a dumb question but I really want to know if it is the right way.

I have a app widget with several `Buttons`. I have created a pending `Intent` to each of these `Buttons` and I've set it using

`setOnClickPendingIntent()`

My question is simple. I have some 9 `Buttons` already and may extend in future. So is it ok to have nine separate pending `Intents` ?

Most of the `Buttons` do the same job but differ in a particular extra field attached with the `Intent`. So any suggestion? because the code looks really dirty with lot of pending `Intents`.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to use a "tag" associated with each controls.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)

It allows you to add a custom value (you define the content, and the format) for each buttons.

When creating your button, add a key to your buttons:

```
button1.setTag((Object) "action1");
button2.setTag((Object) "action2");
```

Define only one pending Intent that you associate to each button.

In the pending intent, get the "tag" of the view, and act accordingly

```
if (((String) view.getTag()).equals("action1"))
    etc...
```

Comment: These buttons are on app widget. App widget uses remote views. And setTags() doesn't seem to be an option on remote views.